# Testing React PropTypes with sinon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme, react-proptypes

As an example I used [Make React PropType warnings throw errors with enzyme.js + sinon.js + mocha.js](https://gist.github.com/scmx/d98cc058a7c3dfef7890).

I have a React component with one required prop:

```
class Pagination extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            ... render some stuff
        );
    }
}

Pagination.propTypes = {
    total: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};
```

And this is test for it:

```
describe('(Component) Pagination', () => {
      before(() => {
         sinon.stub(console, 'error', (warning) => { throw new Error(warning) })
      })
      after(() => { console.error.restore() })

      it('render fails without props', () => {
          shallow(<Pagination />);
      });

      it('render fails without props2', () => {
        shallow(<Pagination />);
      });
    });
```

After running that tests first one crashes, but second - not. Tests are similar.
I think that the problem is that React throws warning messages only once.
How to avoid this?

I want to have 2 tests: one that will be crashed when no props is set, and second works fine with props.

Comment: so did you try beforeEach() and afterEach() to cleanup after each test?  If so, did that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a workaround [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7047):

```
Pagination.displayName = Math.random().toString();
```

You were apparently right that it is because of the same component, and if you do this before each test, then it tricks it. Just a hack, but it works. Apparently no better way.

P.S. I did it in `beforeEach` to not write it in each test myself.
P.P.S. random is not most reliable, since you can get the same name and it will fail, a guid or whatever can be used if it's not good enough, it's just an example.

Comment: personally I think it's much more obvious to other devs if you throw such a thing into a beforeEach.